# showing $e(n + 1) = -e(n)$, where $e(n)=f(n)^2-f(n+1)f(n-1)$ and $f(n)$ is the $n$th term of the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Let $f(n)$ be the Fibonacci sequence, and set $e(n)=f(n)^2-f(n+1)f(n-1)$ for all $n \geq 1$. Show by induction on $n \geq 1$ that $e(n+1)=−e(n)$.

I have prove the base case ($n=1$), but for the induction step, I couldn't figure out. I tried replacing $f(n)$ using recursive relation of fibonacci ($f(n+1)=f(n)+f(n-1)$), but it doesn't lead me anywhere.

Comment: Hint: $\begin{bmatrix}F_{n+2} & F_{n+1}\\ F_{n+1} & F_{n}\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}F_{n+1} & F_n\\ F_n & F_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @achille hui, thanks for help! But I haven't learned matrix multiplication yet, could you please explain this using algebraic equations? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Javi, thanks for editing!

Comment: ok, I think to prove the induction step is to proving e(n+2)=e(n), since we can assume that -e(n+1)=e(n), and what we need to prove is e(n+2)=-e(n+1). But as long as I tried to expand it using recursive relation, I fall into headleass algebraic manipulation. Any tips?

Comment: Hint2: $\require{cancel} F_{n+1} F_{n+1} - F_{n+2} F_n = (\cancel{F_n} + F_{n-1})F_{n+1} - (\cancel{F_{n+1}} + F_n) F_n$

Comment: @achille hui, Thanks! I have successfully proven e(n+1)=-e(n), is this equivalent with an induction procedure?

Comment: For purists, it isn't. We didn't need/use the induction hypothesis at $n$ to prove the statement at $n+1$.

Comment: @achille hui. Thanks!